# Generating all lesser numbers of two coprime numbers

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Let's say I have two coprime positive integers, $a$ and $b$. How would you go about proving that it is possible to make all integers between 1 and $max(a,b)$ by subtracting them from each other? For example, for $a = 7, b = 6$:

$$7-6=1$$
$$6-1 = 5$$
$$7-5=2$$
$$5-2=3$$
$$5-1=4$$

At this point, we have $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$. Why is this true? Thanks!

Comment: When two integers are coprime, you can have a linear combination $sa+tb=1$ for some $s,t$. I suspect you're apply thing this fact implicitly.

Comment: I know that, but how is that relevant to the problem?

Comment: Continuing Ian Cooley: You can apply the $GCD$ algorithm to get the $1$, and the rest is easy.

Comment: That shows that all linear combinations are divisible by 1, which is the gcd, but that doesn't prove the existence of all natural numbers between 1 and a, does it?